# Is it possible to get information on another person's profile? (Instagram API)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

At the moment, I have an application that has passed Facebook verification. In the application, I can additionally connect Instagram within my profile using OAuth. After that, I can use graph.instagram.com to get my profile information.

The problem is that when another profile does the same thing, i.e. connects Instagram in the same way, it will be able to view its Instagram account, but neither its nor my account will be available for each of us.

The question is whether and how to request data on other users if they also connect Instagram and we have the Instagram ID of these profiles, as well as the token of the current user?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `API Instagram Basic Display` for getting your user data.
You can't fetch other users from API.

> The API can be used to access any type of Instagram account but only provides read-access to basic data. If you are building an app that will allow Instagram Businesses or Creators to publish media, moderate comments, identify @mentioned and hashtagged media, or **get data about other Instagram users, use the Instagram Graph API instead**.